# flutter open specific page from button click on webview

Tags: flutter

i am doing an app refactoring of an android application. The point where i am struggling is that on android, on the click of a file picker button on a webview, a custom file picker page is open, called by

```
        override fun onShowFileChooser(
            webView: WebView?,
            filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
            fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
        ): Boolean {
```

of `WebChromeClient()`.

Currently on iPhone the stock file picker is opened, on android nothing happens.

Can i do this in some ways in flutter?

Comment: check out the package file_picker from pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker